# Multipart form data with spring boot and accepting part with content type application/octet-stream

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have the following method:

```
@PostMapping("/my-endpoint", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
fun handleData(@RequestPart part1: FooDto) {
    log.info("Received request: {}", part1)
}
```

It works fine from both postman and my test.

The API i have no control over is specified roughly like this:

```
POST
Content-Length: 7160\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3defr6efr7eea308\r\n
--------------------------3defr6efr7eea308
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part1";
filename="file.json" Content-Type: application/octet-stream
{
  "someCoolId":"11890300",
  // ommissions, but this part is nice human readable json
  "capture":"1623405938252"
}
--------------------------3defr6efr7eea308
// omissions, more parts
```

My postman-request/test only works if 'application/json' is specified for the content type of part1. If i remove this and let it have part1 as application/octet-stream it does not work.

I attempted something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/my-endpoint", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE])
fun handleData(@RequestPart part1: InputStream) {
    // Convert stream to my dto
}
```

And also tried to remove the consumes directive, since I read that in a similar question.

But I just get:

```
"title": "Unsupported Media Type",
"status": 415,
"detail": "Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported.",
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution in the end:

```
@PostMapping("/my-endpoint", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
fun handleData(@RequestPart(name = "part1") part1File: MultipartFile) {
   val dto: FooDTO = try {
        val fileContent = part1File.inputStream
        mapper.readValue(fileContent, FooDTO::class.java)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //handle
    }
 // Do stuff
 }
```